# How to pass HTML parameters to ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a web service project using Bootstrap (HTML&CSS) , Microsoft Access and ASP.NET.

I found a code from W3SCHOOLS of bootstrap login form :

```html
 <body>
    <form method="POST" action="Login.aspx">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Login area</h2>
             <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">UserName:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username1" name="username" placeholder="Enter UserName"/>
                </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
    </div>
   
    <button type="submit" onclick="SubmitForm" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    </div>
```

And this is the C# code :

```
 protected void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string name=string.Format("{0}",Request.Form["username"]);
        string pass = string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["password"]);

        int userId;
        userId = LoginService.GetUserId(name, pass, 0, 1);

        if (userId == 0)
        {
            MessageBoxShow(Page, "UserName does not exists.");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxShow(Page, "You are successfully connected.");
            Session["userId"] = userId.ToString();
            SalService.DeleteFromSal();
        }
    }

}
```

When I am running the page and entering username and password , the page doesnt show the message and I cant connect with the user name.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint and check what is happening at the code-behind and what values are you receiving.

Also, Try using `onserverclick` instead of `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id ="txt"  runat="server"  type="text">
```

and in behine

```
txt.value=@Your
```

Comment: I dont understand what I should write in the behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not formatted using ASP serverside controls, however you can still get it to work. You have to change your button to a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="OK"/>
```

and then change your code behind as follows.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string name=string.Format("{0}",Request.Form["username"]);
        string pass = string.Format("{0}", Request.Form["password"]);

        int userId;
        userId = LoginService.GetUserId(name, pass, 0, 1);

        if (userId == 0)
        {
            MessageBoxShow(Page, "UserName does not exists.");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBoxShow(Page, "You are successfully connected.");
            Session["userId"] = userId.ToString();
            SalService.DeleteFromSal();
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure that the code behind is for a page called login.aspx and should be called login.aspx.cs

There should be a login.aspx page and should have a valid page directive pointing to the code behind.

You will also need a function for MessageBoxShow and the Webservice should be referenced.